# Group acting coprimely by automorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Consider that a group $A$ acts by automorphism on a finite group $G$. If this action is coprime, i.e. $\gcd(|A|,|G|)=1,$ can we affirm that this action is fixed point free, i.e. $C_G(A)=1$?

I tried to think about the order of the automorphism and the order of na element of $G$, but it doesn’t work.

Comment: What does "coprime" mean here? Does it mean $\gcd(|A|, |G|) = 1$?

Comment: What is a coprime action?

Comment: If the action is by automorphisms, the identity will always be a fixed point

Comment: @ahulpke I think a fixed point free action of a group is usually defined to mean one in which only the identity is fixed  i.e. $C_G(A) = 1$, and I am guessing that coprime means $(|A|,|G|)=1$. But the answer to the question is clearly no, coprime actions need not be fixed point free.

Comment: Yes, @QiaochuYuan, coprime action mean gdc(|A|,|G|) = 1

Comment: Google gives many references of results about coprime actions and fixed points. Did you look at these results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Derek Holt pointed out in the comments, the action may have fixed points, even if we don't count the identity.  For example, take $G$ to be the quaternion group of order 8, and let $A = \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ act by cycling $i, j$, and $k$.  This fixes the central element $-1$.